# Convergence of sups of sequence of compactly supported continuous functiosn

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset \Bbb R^n$ be open and bounded and $(f_n)\subset C_c^0(\Omega)$ a sequence which converges pointwise to $f\in C_c^0(\Omega)$. Does $\sup_{x\in\Omega}|f_n(x)|\to \sup_{x\in\Omega}|f(x)|$ as $n\to\infty$? This is obviously true when the convergence is uniform, but we don't have that here. If this is too much to hope for, is at least the sequence $(\sup_{x\in\Omega}|f_n(x)|)$ bounded?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $C^0_c(\Omega)=$ space of continuous function with compact support on $\Omega$, set $\Omega=(0,1)$ and
$$
f_n=n1_{(0,\frac{1}{n}]}+ne^{1-nx}1_{(\frac{1}{n},1)}
$$
$\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $0$ but $\{\sup_{x\in\Omega}|f_n(x)|:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is not even bounded.

Comment: These functions are not continuous, but something along those lines should work.